# How to do before action authenticate for twitter omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know in devise we do

`before_action :authenticate_user!` to force the user to login/sign up form in a specific controller.

I am using `omniauth-twitter` gem. Everything is working fine. I can login and logout. But how do I write a `before_action` authenticate here?

The `authenticate_user!` returns error in omniauth.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Devise** gem with twitter `omniauth` you just have to enable the OmniAuth feature to the corresponding devise model and provide your twitter dev credentials to the devise initializer.

Additionally, you can use [this guide](https://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/) for a step to step set up